# Getting all the text from a web call

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest, xmlserializer

I have the following code and it does what I want it to do.  It gets XML data from a web call and puts it in an object.

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CONFIGURATION_KEY_XE_COM_URL];

        var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xedatafeed));

        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings {XmlResolver = null, DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse};

        var reader = XmlReader.Create(url, settings);

        var feed = (xedatafeed) serialiser.Deserialize(reader);

        return feed;
```

The issue is that I want to get a string representation of this data as well and doing `feed.ToString()` almost gives me all the data but not everything.  There are two things missing

1. The `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` declaration
2. The DTD declaration that came along with the response.

I'd like these two things as well.  I had to exclude the DTD declaration as it was not required for deserialisation into an object and it caused an error when I didn't exclude it.  What's the cleanest way to get the full response given the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it eaiser to either add the  declaration to the string after you have the result from the webservice, or declare it it programatically.

**Method 1 - Add XML declaration after reciept of data**

```
string xmlStr = string.format(@" &lt; ?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"? &gt; {0}", WebServiceStringResult)
```

Then you can create a new XML Document object from the concatenated string with :

```
YourXmlDocumentObject.ReadXML(xmlStr)
```

1. And then loop over or xpath out the desired values.
   or
2. Cast / Manipulate the YourXmlDocumentObject as required.

**Method 2 - Programmatically add the XML/DTD declarations after reciept of data**

In your new XmlDocument object, set the Properties to match your XML version and DTD information.

Finally, just add your webservice result string with:

```
YourXmlDocumentObject.ReadXML(WebServiceStringResult);
```

Note: Soap 1.1 and 1.2 will fall over with the  declaration as part of an embedded request.
ie the  declaration  is inside your one of your web methods.

~ ^i'm still learning to use this ***poxy*** editor, sorry ~

Comment: Hi Aaron, not sure how I can integrate the above into my code.

Comment: Plus, I only want to get what actually is in my response into the string  and not assume that it will contain a particular encoding for instance.  I'd love to see more detail here.

Comment: I guess the question is then, What do you want to do with this 'feed' object once you have created it?

Comment: I want to be able to use it to get data from it.

Comment: Have a look at M$ take on it... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcsyk915.aspx Becuase you are creating an XmlDocument Object, you can rest assured that its of type XML. The M$ example will allow you to Validate it against your DTD.